# Password protected Facebook like-box now showing blank when not log in

Tags: facebook-likebox

We noticed starting from 1/22/2013 our Facebook like-box is now showing a blank box when users are not logged in to Facebook. Previously, our Facebook like-box is showing  log-in and sign up links together with a blank profile photo icon,  when users click the log-in link, a log-in box show up, then the like box is populated properly as soon as the users have logged in.

We did not change anything in our end and we used html 5 version. Here is the web page URL  (http://www.flalottery.com) where our Facebook like-box reside. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: It's a known bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/279190832208178?browse=search_50ff1d3ccd5c75718796271

Answer (score 0):

We've had to turn that box off on a client site. It was worse, in IEs it showed a big cannot load page error.  And I can't see it logged into Facebook or not.

Also if you test on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ changing the URL to anything else also fails. So even facebook seems unable to get the likebox working on their own site :(